# Prevent GridView from scrolling on onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, scroll, android-gridview, android-scroll, android-configchanges

When configuration of the activity changes I apply this code -

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        gridView.setNumColumns(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? 3:2);
        gridView.computeScroll();
    }
```

I want that if the `GridView` is in the midway, it will start from there only but as the configuration changes it is starting all over again from the top.

Comment: Your problem is (or was by now) the use of `gridView.setNumColumns()` which resets the Scroll position. I'm looking for a solution to that right now.

Answer (score 0):

**Add one line to your manifest file**

*No need to override onConfigChanges() method*

```
<activity
            android:name="yourActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a flag and set it to false override method name onConfigurationChangedand in this method set flag true and check if flag is true then disable the scroll and then again false it 
you need to set it in menifest also 
code snipet is following

```
private boolean flag=false;



      @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("ONCONFIGCHANGE", "CALLED" );
            flag = true;
disableScroll();
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }
```

for menifest do the following

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

and in onconfigchange use the following method

```
private void disableScroll()
{
gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

});
}
```